# geo_bounding_box filter parse error Expected [FIELD_NAME] under a [START_OBJECT]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to filter a geohash aggregation with a bounding box filter. But I have a strange error : `Parse Failure [Expected [FIELD_NAME] under a [START_OBJECT], but got a [START_OBJECT] in [traces]]];`

When I don't use this filter, my request works fine.

Here is my request

```
POST /traces/_search?search_type=count&pretty
{
    "aggregations": {
        "traces": {
            "filter": {
                "or": [{
                    "and": [
                      {"term": {"geoip": true}},
                      {"term": {"trackerId": "RG-000000003-1"}}]
                }],
                "geo_bounding_box" : {
                  "loc.coordinates" : {
                      "top_left" : {
                        "lat": 49.109837790524416,
                        "lon": 14.326171874999998
                      },
                      "bottom_right" : {
                          "lat": 44.05601169578525,
                          "lon": -9.404296875
                      }
                  }
              }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "trackerId": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "trackerId",
                        "size": 0
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "heatmap": {
                            "geohash_grid": {
                                "field": "loc.coordinates",
                                "precision": 1

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a part of my mapping where you can see the location.

```
collections: [ {
    name: 'traces',
    index: 'traces',
    type: 'trace',
    mappings: {
        'trace': {
            'properties': {
                'loc': {
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                        'type': {
                            'type': 'string'
                        },
                        'coordinates':{
                            'type': 'geo_point',
                            'geohash':true,
                            'geohash_prefix':true,
                            'lat_lon':true,
                            'fielddata' : {
                                'format' : 'compressed',
                                'precision' : '1cm'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, .....
```

What is wrong with my request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `geo_bounding_box` filter which lies outside the `or` filter. Simply rewrite your query like this:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "traces": {
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "and": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "geoip": true
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "trackerId": "RG-000000003-1"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "geo_bounding_box": {      <--- this need to go inside the "or" array
              "loc.coordinates": {
                "top_left": {
                  "lat": 49.109837790524416,
                  "lon": 14.326171874999998
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                  "lat": 44.05601169578525,
                  "lon": -9.404296875
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "trackerId": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "trackerId",
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "heatmap": {
              "geohash_grid": {
                "field": "loc.coordinates",
                "precision": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ho my ...Thx you Val.

Comment: No prob, glad to help! So many curly braces, so easy to get lost ;-)